# Control large voltage supply using smaller voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transistors

I have a **6** volt supply that I need enable/disable using another **3** volt supply.

If I use a PNP Darlington set-up like this:
[image: PNP setup]
Then I get just under **6** volts at the **Output** node.

My problem is that I don't have any PNP transistors but I do have several NPN transistors and I was hoping that setting up a NPN Darlington would give me similar results, but building something like this yields about **2** volts at the **Output** node:

[image: NPN setup]

My question is; is there a circuit I can make using NPN transistors (*2N2222* to be exact) what will give me a voltage close to **V2** voltage when **V1** is enabled?

Comment: Is your load really only 10k? Or what's the required current?

Comment: @jonk My load is a 6 volt aquarium-pump, I think it's more than 10k but I don't know the details. I can potentially swap the 6 volt supply for a 12 volt if that makes a big difference.

Comment: It's hard to know what to recommend without knowing the required current compliance. Is it possible that you could just measure it? Or does it have a rating on it that tells you "watts"?

Comment: @jonk Current should be less than 250mA.

Comment: Are you controlling it via an MCU output pin? Or what exactly is providing the 3 V controlling voltage?

Comment: @jonk I am using a BBC MicroBit output-pin.

Comment: I see. Do you know if you will be using std-drive or high-drive pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsZFZF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason your circuit doesn't work is because you're using an "emitter follower" circuit. Basically what it does is the transistor maintains a voltage at the emitter that is the same as that at the base, minus a diode drop. Using a darlington in this case doesn't help because the transistor will not conduct if the base is lower than the emitter.

Note that the voltage at the collector of the transistor will not be 6 volts when it is on (you don't want that anyway), however the load will have very close to 6 volts across it when the transistor is switched on.

Edit: as mentioned by @jonk, your micro's output pin does not source enough current to drive this transistor enough to switch your pump. You have a couple of options here, you could buffer the output of your microcontroller through a buffer like a 74HC34, or you could use a darlington configuration with 2 2n2222 transistors as shown here.

Comment: The OP says the load is a motor so (1) you need a kickback diode around the load and (2) the 2N2222 may not handle enough current -- especially at motor start or motor stall.

Comment: Also, assuming \$250\:\text{mA}\$, there won't be sufficient base drive with this circuit. The std-drive I/O is only rated at \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ and the high-drive (only 3 I/Os) is rated at \$5\:\text{mA}\$ max.

Comment: @jonk To be fair, when I posted the answer this information wasn't available.

Comment: Which is why I was asking questions before attempting an answer.

Comment: @C_Elegans I think I got it working with this setup, I had to up the large voltage supply to 12V for it to power the load but that's fine. Thank you so much for helping me with this. If I had a PNP Darlington, would that have worked better?

Comment: @bornander no it wouldn’t. With the PNP transistor, you need to bring the base up to the positive supply to turn it off, which you can’t do with only 3 volts. So you wouldn’t have been able to turn your pump off

Comment: @C_Elegans Could I use a MOSFET transistor of some sort to do this?

Comment: You could. You'd need to pay attention to the mosfet's turn on voltage (needs to be less than 3V) and if you're switching the mosfet rapidly you'll need to use a mosfet driver